# Composer - how do to get root of project?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to use the Composer autoloader located at `vendor/autoload.php`. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get to the root of the project, from which I could then navigate to `vendor/autoload.php`. I'm having to specify the relative path in each file (i.e. `../../../vendor/autoload.php`). This seems like a very nasty way to get to the autoloader, since this path will be different depending on how deep the file is.

Is there a way to get to the root directory without specifying a relative path, or do I need to go up x parent directories in every file?

Comment: What I do is in my config file `define('APPROOT', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../'));` which will then be `/path/to/my/app` and then later `require(APPROOT . '/vendor/autoload.php');`

Comment: @Sammitch How would you go about `include`ing your config then?

Comment: @Sammitch At that point, you might as well put `require_once APPROOT . '/vendor/autoload.php;` in your config file, since (as my answer says) you only need to load it once. I agree with ZeKalk, though,that doesn't really solve the problem of how to find the config file from another file that hasn't loaded it yet.

Comment: Yes, I kind of came at that sideways. IMSoP has the large issues pinned down in that you should really be reducing the points of entry to your application to a minimum. In the ideal case you've just got the one entry point into your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has no way of knowing what the "root of the project" is. You could have any number of directories on your disk, with files called `vendor/autoload.php` in several of them, and only you know what's special about the "project root". So ultimately, the answer is no, there is no way.

However, note that you only need to include the autoloader in *files which aren't themselves included or autoloaded*. The autoloader is something you load *once*, as part of the configuration / bootstrapping of your code, and it then loads whatever classes it needs wherever they're referenced.

So the way to limit the mess of different levels is to structure your project carefully. For instance:

- Route all requests via one or two "routers", such as a single "index.php" file. Use Apache mod_rewrite or the equivalent in Nginx etc to make all URLs actually load this script, and then in the script work out what code to run based on the URL. You can use libraries such as [nikic/FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute/) to translate the URLs into functions to call, which will then be autoloaded.
- Use different PHP files, but all in a reasonably flat directory structure, so that they all have to "climb" the same number of levels to reach the project root.

The same principle applies to use in command-line scripts or any other kind of application: limit or structure the "entry points", because only those need to know where to load the autoloader.

If you already have some kind of config file loaded on every request / script run / unit test / etc, it might be sensible to put the `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';` line in there. Like the configuration, the autoloader is "global state" that you want to just set up once and then forget about.

Comment: So how would I extend a class? I need to include the file I'm extending, therefore don't I need to get to autoloader from every class? (Or at least all the classes that reference other classes)

Comment: @ZeKalk The autoloader only needs to be loaded once, and then it can find whatever class it needs; that's its job. So if your sub-class is loaded via the autoloader, that same autoloader can load any parent classes and other classes referenced in the file, without you needing to add anything. If you had to define a new autoloader for every class, the whole feature would be a lot less useful.

Comment: @ZeKalk Expanded answer with some explanation of how this works.